# Container adjust height automatically with max-height and min-height

Tags: css

I can't figure it out why it doesn't work..maybe I am missing something basic about css (sorry about that).
I want the modal to have a max-height of 90vh and a min-height of 50vh.
The content can change..and when it doesn't fit the 50vh the container grows till a max of 90vh.
If the content doesn't fit the 90vh either, I want the scroll bar. In my case the modal always remains with a height of 50vh and never grows till 90vh. Thanks

```
<div className={styles.overlay}>
      <div className={styles.modal}>
        <div className={styles.inner}>
          <div className={styles.header}>
              <p>{title}</p>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.container}>
              <div className={styles.titleWrapper}>
                 <h1>title</h1>
              </div>
             <div className={styles.appWrapper}>
              {content &&
                content.map((el: any, mainKey: number) => {
                return (
                  <div key={mainKey} className={styles.app}>
                    something here
                  </div>
               );
             })}
            </div>
            <button className={styles.submitBtn}>ok</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

my CSS

```
.header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--dark-grey);
  padding: 16px 16px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: var(--white);
  z-index: 1;
}
 
  .modal {
    width: 680px;
    max-height: 90vh;
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 40vh;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: none;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 12px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
  }

  .overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    z-index: 99;
  }

  .container {
    padding: 32px 40px 40px 40px;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
  .inner {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

Edit: I may have solved it.
Simplified example:

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="content">
    
  </p> 
     <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p><p>text</p> 
  </div>
 
</div>
```

css:

```
.modal {
  width: 500px;
 min-height: 40vh;
  max-height: 90vh;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.content {
 height: 100%; 
  
}
```

Edit 2: My simple example works..if I apply the same logic to my code it doesn't work..I can't understand

Comment: Hi, could you clarify what you want the max and min heights to be? In the text you speak of 90vh and 50vh but in the code I think I'm seeing just 90% and 40%.

Comment: Yes sorry, its correct vh..I mean the height of the modal must be at least the 40vh of the viewport and it can grows till a max of 90vh (of the viewport) according to the content

Comment: If it only works in the code snippet but not in your app, I would imagine you are overriding the style somewhere down the stylesheet as styles further down replace the ones above it, hence "Cascading" Style Sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the simplified example given in the question's edit it does seem to work.

However, if you add a `bottom: 0` which is present in the original code given then that seems to take some precedence over the max-height setting.

I don't claim to understand what priority  woulbottomd have over top plus max-height/height but there does seem to be a difference in behavior.

Here's a snippet without the `bottom: 0`

```css
.modal {
  width: 500px;
 min-height: 10vh;
  max-height: 90vh;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  /* bottom: 0; */
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
 height: 100%; 
  
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="content">
     <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p><p>text</p> 
     <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p><p>text</p> 
     <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p><p>text</p> 
     <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p><p>text</p> 
     <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p><p>text</p> 
     <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p><p>text</p> 
  </div>
 
</div>
```

And here's a snippet with the `bottom: 0;`

```css
.modal {
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 10vh;
  max-height: 90vh;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="content">
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Without "bottom: 0" I have the behavior that I expect..it kinda solve my problem.thank you man